# bash: showing executed commands expect echos

Tags: debugging, bash, command, echo

I like using the `-x` switch with bash to debug scripts. The only downside is that the `echo` commands are also display which may create a lot of unnecessary duplicates:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Changing to /etc directory"
cd /etc
```

Then once run:

```
$ bash -x test.sh 
+ echo 'Changing to /etc directory'
Changing to /etc directory
+ cd /etc
```

I tried filtering out with `bash -x test.sh | grep -v '+ echo'` but it doesn't work.

**[Q] Is there a way I can prevent `-x` to also display `echo` commands?**

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that -x is writing to stderr and you are only piping stdout.  Just change your grep to this:
bash -x test.sh 2>&1 | grep -v '+ echo'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter it through a regex engine of your choice:

```
$ ./test.sh 2>&1 | awk '{if(!match($0, /^\+ echo/)){print $0}}'
```

or

```
$ ./test.sh 2>&1 | grep -v '^\+ echo'
```

Comment: If you are going to filter your output, wouldn't it be simpler to just  use `grep -v '^+ echo'`? That's kind of clumsy use for `awk`.

Comment: tested but doesn't work. Something interesting I noticed is that I can't even grep out the output with `grep -v` when I use `bash -x` whereas doing with `echo "something" grep -v` works.

Comment: @Caleb Yes, that's a much better idea. I forgot about that option :)

@user359650 bash -x is writing to stderr. You need to pipe stderr to stdout and grep that. I updated my answer with an example.